# Item View Limit

Tags: list, list-view, item, list-view-threshold

I'll do my best to explain this.

So I have created a custom list with 5 columns

- Group (Single line of text) - Not done as choice as using datasheet view to upload these
- Category (Single line of text)
- Title (Single Line of text)
- Day Cost (Currency)
- Night Cost (Currency)

The issue is coming from there being roughly 4250 items for each group and is forcing above the item view limit.

I have created 5 separate views (one for each group) and modified the view so that it will filter by group and then group by category. In theory this should mean that in any one view there should only be a total of 4250 which is within the threshold however now I have added 5000 items in total to the list none of these views will work and I'm presented with a message saying that all the views are above the threshold.

My question is does anyone know how i can resolve this or break up the view to stay within the threshold.

Comment: Did you setup an index on Group?

Comment: Hello Nate, Yes I had to remove the list items and then create indexes. I didn't know this had to be done first and had already began adding items before realizing there was no indexes for the list.

Comment: Yes, I've learned this the painful way as well.  Hope it's working for you now. : )

Answer (score 1):

Quickest solution would be to filter via ID; and use the "Equal to" and "Less Then" to sort your view. 
ID equal to 1 less then 4.999
ID equal to 5.000 less then 9.999

As an example. Then you will definitely not have more the 5.000 items.